# sql - Query to get the teams that were in the top 6 in the last 5 years of a championship

Tags: sql, sqlite

So basically I have 3 tables:

```
teams(id, name)

championship(id, name, year)

results(id_team, id_championship, points)
```

I want to get the teams that were in the top 6 of a particular championship in the last 5 years.

What I did by now is join all the tables with inner join and filtered by year.

The problem is, I don't know how to limit filter the top 6 and somehow show this result.

I know this is probably a very basic question but I'm wasting a lot of time on it.

## EDIT:

```
select * from teans as t 
inner join result as r 
inner join championship as c
on t.id=r.id_team and c.id=r.id_championship
where ano between 2012 and 2017;
```

This is what I have by now. Now, I don't know how to make a top 6 query inside a group by clause, this is what I was thinking. Group by year and limit the top 6 results.

I'm pretty beginner in SQL so I know I'm not thinking this 100% right.

## EDIT2:

The tables I'm using to test. I'm just trying to search the years 1999 and 2000. Just to make it easier for now.

```
+---------+--------------+--------+
|   id    |     name     |  year  |
+---------+--------------+--------+
|     "1" | "Brasileito" | "1999" |
|     "2" | "Brasileito" | "2000" |
|     "3" | "Brasileito" | "2001" |
+---------+--------------+--------+

+---------+-----------------+------+
| id_team | id_championship | year |
+---------+-----------------+------+
|    "1"  | "1"             | "10" |
| "2"     | "1"             | "7"  |
| "3"     | "1"             | "7"  |
| "4"     | "1"             | "7"  |
| "5"     | "1"             | "7"  |
| "1"     | "2"             | "10" |
| "2"     | "2"             | "7"  |
| "3"     | "2"             | "11" |
| "4"     | "2"             | "7"  |
| "5"     | "2"             | "6"  |
+---------+-----------------+------+

+-----+-------------+-------+
| id  |    name     | state |
+-----+-------------+-------+
| "1" | "Cruzeiro"  | "MG"  |
| "2" | "Flamengo"  | "RJ"  |
| "3" | "Vasco"     | "RJ"  |
| "4" | "Galo"      | "MG"  |
| "5" | "São Paulo" | "SP"  |
+-----+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Please see minimal, complete verifiable example so we can help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I posted in the edit what I have by now.

Comment: I'm having to do this in SQLite. So I have pretty much the basic SQL stuff.

Comment: I suggest starting simple and building up to the answer.  How about the top 6 for 1 year?

Comment: This I can do, but I don't know how to do it with all the 5 years in one query.

Comment: can you put in some actual data so we can see?

Comment: I can't really access the actual data right now, I'm using data that I created myself to test. I can try to put it in the comment if it will help but it is very basic.

Comment: @WilsonPena edit the question and add the test data.

Comment: I posted. I'm just trying to search 2 years and looking for the top team. But the idea is the same as in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calculating a championship *rank* with correlated sub query and then use it to filter top 6:

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT * FROM teams AS t 
   INNER JOIN result AS r 
   INNER JOIN championship AS c
     ON t.id=r.id_team AND c.id=r.id_championship
   WHERE ano BETWEEN 2012 AND 2017)

SELECT main.*
FROM 
  (SELECT t.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM cte sub
                WHERE sub.points >= t.points 
                AND sub.ano = t.ano
                AND sub.id_championship = t.id_championship) AS rank
   FROM cte t) AS main
WHERE main.rank <= 6
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you the list of teams who scored the most points in a given championship limited to top 6. Not sure if this is what you wanted?

```
SELECT *
FROM RESULTS AS R
INNER JOIN TEAMS AS T ON T.ID = R.ID_TEAM
INNER JOIN CHAMPIONSHIP AS C ON C.ID = R.ID_CHAMPIONSHIP
WHERE C.YEAR >= add_months( sysdate, -12*5 
ORDER BY R.POINTS DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Yes, but this has to be done in the last 5 years. So I have to get the teams that were in the top 6 in any of the last 5 years.

Comment: I editted the sql query for last 5 years @WilsonPena

Comment: this isn't giving me the top 6 in each year. its just giving the overall top 6 by points.